# Scrapy Xpath: Extracting @title from img node

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-shell

I want to extract the `@title` from the *Main Notes According to Your Votes* section from this page: https://www.fragrantica.com/perfume/Remy-Latour/Cigar-9351.html

I have fetched the HTML, then tried this line of code on `scrapy shell` but the output was `None`:

```
response.xpath('//*[@id="userMainNotes"]/div/img/@title).extract_first()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work

```
response.xpath('//span[contains(@id, "note")]/img[@rel]/@title')
```

Do not forget to set USER AGENT to your settings.py

[Crawler data form website use Scrapy 1.5.0 - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50712607/crawler-data-form-website-use-scrapy-1-5-0-python/50716860#50716860)

Comment: Thank you Yash, your code worked. However may I ask you to clarify the logic behind your line of code? Especially what the img[@rel] part stands for ...

Comment: @AnhQuocVo your welcome, sure I can tell you the logic behind it

Comment: You might have written that xpath according to the html node arrangement in chrome/firefox's developer inspect tool. Correct me if I'm wrong. Well It isn't always same as you are getting in your response. because browser has compiled it. which rearrange the nodes where your python lover level request can't do that.

Comment: yes you are correct, I have copied the xpath straight from the inspect tool. For some other elements such as the name of the product this has worked ... but not for the perfume notes. I have chosen your answer as the solution to this question however my reputation is low thus I cannot upvote.

Comment: Now if you want to write 100% correct xpath then you have to save the response and write xpath according to that response body.  you could refer to this https://medium.com/@yashpokar/scrape-any-website-in-the-internet-without-using-splash-or-selenium-68a6c9733369

Answer (score 2):

If you check source code (`Ctrl+U`) you'll find:

```
<div title="96:241;171:117;33:103;34:103;41:70;128:63;4:59;182:59;170:58;75:56;191:48;21:39;77:39;14:28" id="userMainNotes">Loading...</div>
```

that means that above `<div>` is rendered by Javascript that's why your code doesn't work.

Comment: thank you gangabass, what efficient methods do you suggest for crawling javascript heavy pages ?